# Find a property of groups that is inherited by subgroups but not by quotients.

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, quotient-group

This is **Exercise 4.6b** of Roman's *"Fundamentals of Group Theory: An Advanced Approach"*. Part a is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3935094/104041). According to [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgroup-theory%5D+%22inherited+by+subgroups%22) and [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=Inherited%20by%20subgroups%20but%20not%20by%20quotients&p=1), it is new to MSE.

### The Details:

From p.116 of Roman's book,

> **Definition**: Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a property of groups. [ . . . ] We write $G\in \mathcal{P}$ if $G$ has property $\mathcal{P}$. [ . . . ] A property $\mathcal{P}$ of groups is *inherited* by subgroups if $$G\in \mathcal{P}\text{ and }H\le G\implies H\in \mathcal{P},$$ and $\mathcal{P}$ is inherited by quotients if $$G\in \mathcal{P}\text{ and }H\unlhd G\implies G/H\in \mathcal{P}.$$

### The Question:

> Find a property of groups that is inherited by subgroups but not by quotients.

### Thoughts:

The property cannot be "virtually $\mathcal{Q}$" for some property $\mathcal{Q}$ by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/128819/104041) by Arturo Magidin to some other question, where "$G$ is *virtually $\mathcal{X}$*" means that there exists $H\le G$ of property $\mathcal{X}$ such that $[G:H]$ is finite. So, in particular, it cannot be finite.

Please help :)

Comment: What about "$G$ is free"?

Comment: How about $G$ is torsion-free?

Comment: That works, @lulu.

Comment: That works too, @hardmath.

Comment: Thank you both!

Comment: Here is a weirder example: the property of having finite asymptotic dimension passes to subgroups but not quotients. Or more generally having asymptotic dimension $\leq n$ for some fixed $n$

Comment: Note that my answer requires the property $Q$ be inherited by quotients. Of course, if you already had a property that was not inherited by quotients, you wouldn’t need to consider “virtually $Q$”...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the answers to your other question uses the following general pattern: the condition that a certain type of equation is always solvable in a group (e.g. the condition that every element have a square root) is inherited by quotients but usually not by subgroups.

There's a sort of dual to this: the condition that a certain type of equation is *not* solvable in a group is inherited by subgroups but usually not quotients. For example, the condition that there exist no nontrivial solutions to $g^n = 1$ (which is exactly the condition of being torsion-free) works.